# Using DateTimePicker in WinForms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to `select` some records from a MSSQL database based on a date through a C# app (WinForms) and I'm using the following code:

```
string select = @"
select 
    g.nume as Gestiune, 
    p.cod as NumarNIR, 
    p.doc_cod as DocumentDeBaza, 
    p.Validat as Validat, 
    p.Facturat as Contat 
from 
    primar p 
        inner join gestiuni g 
        on p.part2=g.gest_id 
           and data= '" + dtpNIR.Value.ToString() + "' 
           and cod='" + txtNIR.Text +"'";
```

The error I get when I try to `select` the records:

> the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

I have been looking for answers but all I could find was about using the `insert` statement using `datetimepicker`. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: what is dateTimePicker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sql parameters.
Using parameters eliminate all kind of formatting problems in passing values to the query.

```
string select = @"
    select 
        g.nume as Gestiune, 
        p.cod as NumarNIR, 
        p.doc_cod as DocumentDeBaza, 
        p.Validat as Validat, 
        p.Facturat as Contat 
    from 
        primar p 
            inner join gestiuni g 
            on p.part2=g.gest_id 
                and data=@DateNIR 
                and cod=@TextNIR";

SqlParameter[] parameters = 
{
    new SqlParameter("@DateNIR", dtpNIR.Value),
    new SqlParameter("@TextNIR", txtNIR.Text)
}

using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString)
{
    using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(select, conn)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        conn.Open()
        //Execute command
    }
}
```

Using parameters will defend against [Sql Injection attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)
Improve performance of queries if parameter's properties defined correctly according to database schema (re-use of compiled query plans)